# longpress gesture recognizer doesn't work on user location (MKuserlocation) on map view - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, location, mkmapview, gesture

I have a MapView in my application. Showuserlocation is active.
I added GestureRecognizer for long press.
Everything works correctly.

By cons, when I touch the annotation of the user (blue circle), the gesture event is not receive.

how can intercepted the gesture on the annotation of the user?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can add gesture to detect long press by modifying with minor change in above code.

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
    {



    UILongPressGestureRecognizer* _longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDetected:)];
    _longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.0;
    _longPressRecognizer.accessibilityValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",totalMenues];
    [pinView addGestureRecognizer:_longPressRecognizer];

    }

    - (void) longPressDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding gesture on annotation.So you need to add gesture to every annotation.And there is no need to add gesture to annotation because of there are two method.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

If you wanna then

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation)annotation
{
    // Reuse or create annotation view

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longTap = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longTapRecgonized:)];
    longTap.delegate = self;
    [annotationView addGestureRecognizer:longTap];
}

- (void)longTapRecognized:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    // Handle double tap on annotation view
}
```

Comment: thank you,
but I really need to use a gesture recognizer to detect longpress (one second).
how to add gesturereconizer on the annotation user?

Comment: Doesn't work ! I don't understand why. But your code is good.

Comment: My code
     
    -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
        lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 0.3;
        lpgr.delegate=self;
        
        MKAnnotationView *view = [self.mapView viewForAnnotation:(MKUserLocation *)annotation];
        
        [view addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
        return view;
 }
}
`

Comment: your code is also good but may be you have done some mistake.

Comment: may be the view is changed when it is updated. So the gesture is lost? Otherwise I do not see the error!

Comment: +1 OMG thanks this worked beautifully for me. I added this before, but one think I want to add to this is that you need to set the min pressure to low so it gets picked up before the callout view. Did this in Xcode 7.3, swift.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented follwing method of `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`?

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

The method should return YES, so gesture recognizer works with others.